# CSS border-image - critical

Tags: css

I did this with CSS:
[image]

But I want my Client to change the image frame. In my image, current frame is simply a color (#000). But the frame can be decorative. So the client should use decorative image for framing. I've seen the [W3Schools' border-image property lesson](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

The syntax is:

```
border-image: source slice width outset repeat;
```

But using an image like the following I couldn't manage to do that.

[image]

- I can't understand: How the syntax is dynamic for the border image's dimension (width-height)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The border-image property is one of the properties introduced in CSS3 for the purposes of enabling images to be used on CSS borders.

The CSS border-image property is a shorthand property for setting multiple “border image” related properties in one place. In other words, the border-image property is an efficient way of adding images to your borders.

```
div{-webkit-border-image: url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round;-moz-border-image: url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round;-ms-border-image: url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round;-o-border-image: url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round;border-image: url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round;}
```

This link May Helpful for you.

http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/

Best of Luck:);

Answer (score 2):

I've found a border-image generator that shows how the x and y values change as you move the bars.
Here's the link:

http://border-image.com/

Hope this helps...