# How to coordinate jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

With the [previous assistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809999/css-border-image-critical) regarding border-image, I did the custom framing correctly.
Here is a snap:
[image: Border Image using CSS]

Here is my code:

HTML with Inline CSS:

```
<div class="image-border" style="border-width: 10px; -moz-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;   -webkit-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat; -o-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat; border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;">
     <img src="images/product-img.jpg" alt="Product Image With Specifications" width="277" height="auto"/>
</div> <!-- .image-border -->
```

Other External CSS:

```
.image-border img{
    margin: 5% 5%;
    max-width: 340px;
    border: 1px solid #686868;
    }

.image-border{
    background: #999;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    max-width: 370px;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000;
    /* BORDER IMAGE FOR DYNAMIC USE */
    border-style: solid;    
    }
```

Now I need my admin-user to do it dynamically. In an art shop, there will be some frames (admin-user will upload them), and the visitor-user will simply click on a frame and it will wrap-up the image accordingly.

The problem is: to do such thing I need to use jQuery. But the typical jQuery uses the `<img/>` tag and switch between one to other. There are some *thumb-frame.jpg* and some *frame.jpg*. When I click on the thumb-frame the JS simply delete the *"thumb"* portion of the file name and loads the *frame.jpg*. The switching works for `<img/>` to `<img/>` tag. But the `border-image` thing is a CSS property, not HTML's `<img/>` property.

I tried **[THIS ONE](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/jquery-animate-and-transfer-effect-with-image/)**.

Here comes the problem:

- **How can I coordinate jQuery with CSS property?**

One things come to my mind is, loading a separate CSS class for each types of frame. But can't understand how to proceed.

Anybody?

Comment: CSS properties can be accessed via jQuery/javascript - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions to your problem. Here are just a few of many:

- **jQuery's `.css` function:**
  As @Ishank pointed out, you can use the `.css` function to directly change the element's css. The function has numerous syntaxes, which can read about at http://api.jquery.com/css/ . For your specific problem, the following syntax may be the best option.
  e.g.

```
//Sets Properties. Replace "url(..." with an empty string "" to reset property
$('.image-border').css({
    '-webkit-border-image': "url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round",
    '-moz-border-image': "url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round",
    '-ms-border-image': "url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round",
    '-o-border-image': "url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round",
    'border-image': "url(/properties/border-image-1.png) 30 30 round"
});
```

- **jQuery's `.addClass` and `.removeClass` functions:**
  As their names would suggest, these two functions allow you to add and remove classes. So one way to resolve your problem would be (using a more specific selector)
  `$('.image-border').removeClass('image-border');`
- **jQuery's `.wrap` and `.unwrap` functions**
  These two functions allow you to wrap a new element around the selected objects or to delete the parent of the selected objects. I wouldn't really recommend this option, as I personally avoid repeatedly adding/removing elements from the dom. But you could implement this by using unwrap on the object that you're deselecting and then wrapping the clicked img with the div.

  e.g.

```
$('.image-border img').unwrap();
$('#newimg').wrap("<div class='image-border' style='border-width: 10px; -moz-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;   -webkit-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat; -o-border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat; border-image: url(images/frame.png) 10 10 10 10 repeat;'>");
```

These are just a few ways of many to solve you're problem. I would recommend the `.addClass` / `.removeClass` solution as it's the cleanest, as all the styling stays the same, and you only deal with classes. Let me know if this all makes sense and if this was helpful :)